# Gitlab CI and YAML for Dotnet Framework 4.6.1 - Selenium Automation

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, gitlab-ci

I am working on a Selenium Automation for a UnitTest Project in Dotnet Framework 4.6.1 and implementing Gitlab CI using a shared runner.

Created the YAML file and used `image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:3.1`

The `dotnet build` command is failing with error message -

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.406/Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1177,5): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (sdk/Targetting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application.

Any suggestion on -

Q1. How I can resolve this error so I can build my project? If I need to install the developer pack what should be the YAML step to install the developer pack for Dotnet 4.6.1?

Q2. If I use `msbuild` to build the project then the command is not being recognized. Is there any way to use `msbuild` command?

Note# These build commands are working in my local.

[YAML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qQv5.jpg)

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXM0x.jpg)

Comment: The image you are using is for dotnet core version 3.1. It's not for netFw 4.6.1

Comment: Thanks Amir. Do you have suggestions on the Dotnet framework 4.6.1 image please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the image on Docker hub, it doesn't appear to have a 4.6.1 version available. The available images are listed in the "Full Tag Listing" about half way down the page. If the 5.0 tags don't work for you, there's methods to contact Microsoft about that image under "Support" or "Feedback" at the bottom of the page.

https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-sdk/